# Scanner constructor causes bufferedReader to return null

Tags: java, constructor, null, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Im trying to do -

```
BufferedReader br = new BuffereReader(file);
Scanner s = new Scanner(br);
sys.out(s.next());
sys.out(buffReader.readLine());
```

What I expect to happen is to now have 2 separate readers on the file pointing at different places. However, the buffReader returns null on the readLine, while the scanner seems to work fine. Is it possible for me to have 2 readers like I want?

Comment: You can not achieve that thing using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I expect to happen is to now have 2 separate readers on the file pointing at different places.

Your expectation is misplaced. In the first place, both are connected to the same underlying file, which only has one current position. In the second place, the Scanner is wrapped around the BufferedReader, so any change in the position causes by the Scanner happens *via* the BufferedReader.

Comment: Im not sure if anything that happens to the Scanner happens via the BufferedReader. Can't the Scanner make create a copy of BufferedReaders resources so that it has its own?

Comment: @Dgrin91 I've just answered that. Asking again doesn't change the answer.